# problem with building boost function get_io_service

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am using c++ with boost on debian. I have a problem with compiling

```
....
auto& service = socket_->get_io_service();
```

....

I have an error
no member named 'get_io_service' in 'asio::basic_datagram_socket'
I am using 3rd party library and this code is there.
I checked that the function is in this check:

#if !defined(ASIO_NO_DEPRECATED)

is ther a way to activate this function